# I need a list of references for MS Access 2013 for *.accdb files after trying to convert 2002 *mdb to 2013 *.accdb

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is my problem: I have an MS Access database whose development was started several years ago with Access 2002 and continued with Access 2013 in *.mdb and *.mde formats. This database uses DAO and works well in Access 2013.

But now I would like to update the base to *.accdb and *.accde formats. The conversion has succeeded, but will not compile because the compiler signals the following instruction as an error: "R.Edit", where "R" is a recordset which needs to be modified.

This seems to me to be a problem with the list of references needed for Access 2013 for *accdb files, as I assume I do not have the correct version of DAO or the equivalent for Access 2013 accdb. I have looked for a list of the required references, but so far have not found anything up to date (I found something from Microsoft for Access 2003, but not for Access 2013).

So :
1. What versions of what references are needed for Access 2013?
2. What instructions, if any, need to be changed to make an Access *.mdb database work as an *.accdb database in Access 2013, using these references?

Footnote:
For any given version of Access to work, it is vital to have the correct version of the needed references. I have run into this problem several times, but I have never found a clear statement of what versions of what references are required for a given version and context of Access, DAO/ADO, Active_X, etc. So it has been very hit and miss before I finally found the correct version of the needed reference.

If anybody can supply a link to such a list, I am sure that many people who are converting from older versions of Access will find it an invaluable guide.

David Llewellyn

Comment: One thing to check: Is `R` defined as `Dim R As Recordset` or is it defined as `Dim R As DAO.Recordset`? Many versions ago Microsoft changed the default data access mechanism for Access VBA projects from DAO to ADO, and then reversed its decision and changed the default back to DAO. If both references are included in the project then an unqualified `Recordset` object will map to the reference with the higher priority (closer to the top of the list of references) and that can cause confusion. I recommend that one always uses the `DAO.` or `ADODB.` qualifier when declaring such objects.

Comment: The easy way to get such list is to create a fresh .accdb database, then goto the VBA editor and see what the references are.